# Spawn objects by timer or something else. c# unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to spawn objects in in my positions list but with timer!

Because i have a lot of object so when i spawn them it's takes time to spawn so we need to do it with timer every 1-2 seconds spawn one object.

or, create int and his value is `MyList.count`
and when the count and my list have all objects.

when object in list = `Null` will removed automatically from our list so our list count will decreased, for each 1 decrease spawn 1 object,

**my idea is:** I'm working in FPS game and i have enemies with missions when i spawn all agents on one time it's takes a long time to run.

so i want solution to fix this by spawn the mission agents when i complete previous mission.

Anybody have another idea make my game works fast with a lot of agents?

Comment: you can use a coroutine.

Comment: It sounds like you're spawning every enemy in the level at once which means you're wasting resources creating/maintaining any enemies not immediately relevant to the player. Just spawn groups of them based on events like a player completing a task or entering an area.

Comment: Can you provide some code that you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a similar thing in my game. I wanted to spawn platforms on a timer so I used DeltaTime and made a loop that would only spawn a platform when the timer ran out. For you I would not recommend using the random generator for your time because you want it to spawn every two seconds. See my implementation below:

```
    /**
     * Use this for initialization
     */
    void Start () {
        waitingTime = Random.Range(1f, 1.35f);
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    /**
     * Update is called once per frame
     */
    void Update () {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer > waitingTime)
        {
            createPlatform();
            timer = -20;
        }
```

This is very simple. Upon creation of the object a timer is started. When the timer is out the object spawns a new one of itself which will then create another and so on. Another suggestion would be putting the timer on some external object so you can count how many objects you are creating more easily. Please let me know if you have any more questions!